# Extend c3js library to include my own functionality & features

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How can I extend http://c3js.org/ library, I wanted to replace its internal initialisation function or redrawing functions with my own code.

```
 c3_chart_internal_fn.initParams = function () {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that is defined here:

https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/src/core.js

So yes, you could download the source from github and make your desired changes.

This library uses Grunt to concatenate (and minify) all the source files into the single library file used by your web pages.  The gruntfile is in the sources as well.  If you are not familiar with grunt, see: http://gruntjs.com/

Alternatively, it looks like  c3_chart_internal_fn is global.  If that is true, you **may** be able to simply redefine c3_chart_internal_fn.initParams after you load the library (sigma.js plugins work that way).

However, I have not looked at the code carefully enough to see when this function gets called.  If it is called as soon as the library loads (as part of an immediately evaluated function), then it will be too late to redefine.  However, if it is called when you init the library in your page's script, then that would work.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in http://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/releases/tag/0.3.0 the new architecture that supports extensions.